# Cereal Binary Archive Serialize/Deserialize

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, cereal

I'm using the following code to attempt to serialize/deserialize an object as binary data:

```
MyDTO dto1;    
std::ostringstream os(std::stringstream::binary);
{
    cereal::BinaryOutputArchive oarchive(os); // Create an output archive
    oarchive(dto1);
}

MyDTO dto2;

std::istringstream is(os.str(), std::stringstream::binary);
{
    cereal::BinaryInputArchive iarchive(is); // Create an input archive
    try {
        iarchive(dto2);
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error e) {
        e.what();
    }
}
```

<strike>When the code runs, an exception is caught with the message:</strike>

`"Failed to read 8 bytes from input stream! Read 0"`

Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong?

Comment: You should show us the input file

Comment: There is no input file, I'm reading and writing to strings.

Comment: istringstream construction is fixed and seems to work properly now.

Answer (score 1):

Your input archive `iarchive` has no data to read from since `is` is empty. You should first write to the `stringstream` using output archive and use the same stringstream for `iarchive` to read from (I guess that is what you want to do)

You should try something like below (I did not test it):

```
MyDTO dto1;    
std::stringstream os(std::stringstream::binary);
{
    cereal::BinaryOutputArchive oarchive(os); // Create an output archive
    oarchive(dto1);
}

MyDTO dto2;

{
    cereal::BinaryInputArchive iarchive(os); // Create an output archive
    try {
        iarchive(dto2);
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error e) {
        e.what();
    }
}
```

Comment: In simplifying my code, I left out where I read ostream back into istream. Question is updated.

Comment: You are still doing no different than what I have shown IMO. Do you see any issue with my solution ?

Comment: Well the question is updated, but there is no question now :)

Comment: Your solution isn't exactly right, but it did help show me I wasn't constructing my istringstream right.